# AccessControlException in Hadoop for access=EXECUTE

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, execute, accesscontrolexception

I have a small application which reads a file from my local machine and writes the data into hdfs.

Now i want to list the files present in the hdfs folder, say HadoopTest. When i try to do that , i am getting the below exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=rpoornima, access=EXECUTE, inode="/hbase/HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_1.txt":rpoornima:hbase:-rw-r--r--
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:4523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getListingInt(FSNamesystem.java:3312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getListing(FSNamesystem.java:3289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getListing(NameNodeRpcServer.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1687)
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. kindly give you inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You exception is clear enough to show the problem.

As the exception says

```
Permission denied: user=rpoornima, access=EXECUTE,
inode="/hbase/HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_1.txt":rpoornima:hbase:-rw-r--r--`
```

This means your account `rpoornima` only has `-rw-r--r--` permission(*no execute*) on the file `/hbase/HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_1.txt`. So you have to use another full privilege account to do the execution.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to give access to specified user. Use a [chmod](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#chmod) command.

> chown
>
> Usage: hadoop fs -chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] URI [URI ]
>
> Change the owner of files. The user must be a super-user. Additional information is in the Permissions Guide.
>
> Options
>
> The -R option will make the change recursively through the directory structure.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Another user 'hdfs' and 'root' have full access. But not sure how to access the  'HadoopTest' folder as user 'root' from java code. any idea how to access as a different user?

Comment: The exception said you are using `user=rpoornima`, which has no privilege on the specified directory. Not the `root`.

Comment: The user=rpoornima is given full access as given below in the passwd file: rpoornima:x:102:106

I figured out that each time i write a new file, the permission is getting reset to -rw-r--r--. Hence in the java code, i set the permission as given below:
     
  'Path path = new Path((hdfsurl.append("/hbase/HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_"+filecount+".txt")).toString());
   os = hdfs.create(path);
   hdfs.setPermission(path,new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL));'

After this the file is written with the below permission: 
-rw-rw-rw-   3 rpoornima hbase   HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_1.txt

Comment: Still, when i execute the code in java, i am getting the same exception:

org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=rpoornima, access=EXECUTE, inode="/hbase/HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_1.txt":rpoornima:hbase:-rw-rw-rw-

Comment: You failed to add `EXECUTE` access,  as the exceptions said `-rw-rw-rw-`.

Comment: How do i add EXECUTE access in java code? I implemented the code 'hdfs.setPermission(path,new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL));
     hdfs.setPermission(path,new FsPermission(FsAction.EXECUTE,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL));', but still getting the access exception.

Comment: If i have excute access, what will the syntax of the permission look like??

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx` is full access for file.

Comment: Any idea how to write the file in hdfs with execute access? I tried various methods. Still not working: Currently my code looks like below:hdfs = FileSystem.get(
       new URI(hdfsurl.toString()), conf);
     Path path = new Path((hdfsurl
       .append("/hbase/HadoopTest/Hadoop_File_"+filecount+".txt"))
       .toString());
     os = hdfs.create(path);
     
     hdfs.setPermission(path,new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL));
     hdfs.setPermission(path,new FsPermission(FsAction.EXECUTE,FsAction.ALL,FsAction.ALL));
 
     IOUtils.copyBytes(is, os, 4096, false);